# How do I properly nest paste() functions in R?

Tags: r

Can you tell me why

```
paste(paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", "), "third", collapse=" and ")
```

gives me

```
"first, second third"
```

instead of

```
"first, second and third"
```

? What would be the correct syntax to get the second output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Explanation

It is a subtle difference in how you are calling the function. In

```
paste(c("first", "second"), collapse = ", ")
```

note that you are passing only one argument via `...` which is a vector of length 2. This results in a vector of length 1 returned:

```
> paste(c("first", "second"), collapse = ", ")
[1] "first, second"
```

You then pass this length 1 vector **and** a second length 1 vector via `...` in the outer `paste()`. In effect you are doing:

```
paste("first, second", "third", collapse = " and ")
```

As both supplied vectors are of length 1, there is nothing to collapse over, the two strings are just concatenated with the separator `sep`.

Hence, in the first case,

```
paste(c("first", "second"), collapse = ", ")
```

there is no second vector to paste values on to the first, hence `paste()` collapses the elements of the single vector `c("first", "second")` using `", "` as the separator. But when you pass in two length 1 vectors, in

```
paste("first, second", "third", collapse = " and ")
```

the function concatenates the two strings into a single string `"first, second third"` using `sep`, and then as there is just a length 1 character, there is nothing to collapse over.

#### Specific solution

If all you want is the string `"first, second, and third"` and you have the inputs as per your example, just switch to using `sep = ", and "` instead:

```
paste(paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", "), "third", sep = ", and ")
```

which gives

```
> paste(paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", "), "third", sep = ", and ")
[1] "first, second, and third"
```

or

```
> paste(paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", "), "third", sep = " and ")
[1] "first, second and third"
```

if you don't want the Oxford comma.

#### Summary

The easiest way to see how `sep` and `collapse` relate to the supplied inputs. Two examples are illustrative:

```
> paste(1:5, letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5], sep = " ")
[1] "1 a A" "2 b B" "3 c C" "4 d D" "5 e E"
> paste(1:5, letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5], sep = " ", collapse = "-")
[1] "1 a A-2 b B-3 c C-4 d D-5 e E"
```

We observe two features:

1. `sep` applies element-wise to the input vectors, e.g. to `1`, `a`, and `A`; then `2`, `b`, and `B`; and so on.
2. `collapse` applies to the result of the first paste step using `sep` *if* that results in a vector of length >= 2 by concatenating the elements with the separator given by the argument `collapse`. Without `collapse`, `paste()` can return a vector of multiple strings if given vector inputs, but with `collapse` specified only a length 1 character vector will be returned.

Comment: I made a tweak to show that `sep` doesn't just apply pair-wise, and changed what I perceived to be a typo. If that's out of line, please revert edit and let me know.

Comment: @BlueMagister Thanks for this; I toyed with adding a third vector or wondered if the pair-wise might be taken literally and not in this instance. Went with simplicity as this was already a long answer, but your edit is a much better explanation now. +1

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
paste(paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", "), "third", sep=", and ")
## "first, second, and third"
```

And see this blog post on pasting: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/paste-paste0-and-sprintf-2/

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down:

1st part:

```
> paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", ")
#[1] "first, second"
```

2nd part:

```
> paste("first, second", "third", collapse=" and ")
#[1] "first, second third"
```

using sep= instead of collapse=

```
> paste("first, second","third",sep=" and ")
#[1] "first, second and third"
```

Therefore you can use:

```
> paste(paste(c("first", "second"), collapse=", "), "third",sep=", and ")
#[1] "first, second, and third"
```